# Docker flask cant connect

Tags: python, macos, flask, docker

I am trying to do 
http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html

I have copied the tutorial verbatim, except I changed

```
From flask import Flask
```

to

```
from flask import Flask
```

I can built it just fine.  I can start it and get the following when I run docker ps from the command line

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
291c8dfe5ddb        whatever:latest     "python app.py"     About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   sick_wozniak
```

I am building this on OSX

I have tried the following

1. Looking at this post [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)
2. Running $ python app.py to make sure it works without docker
3. Creating a django project and a dockerfile for that project.  Then build, run and access.

So I am confident that docker is working and flask is working independently of each other, but I cannot get them to work together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If on Linux, then `http://localhost:5000` should work seeing as the container is both running and listening on port 5000.

Otherwise, you would be using Docker Machine, and so you need to get the IP of the docker virtual machine using `docker-machine ip`. On OSX, for example

```
$ open http://$(docker-machine ip default):5000
```

Comment: Yeah, Docker on OSX or Windows doesn't make any sense because it's still in a VM

Comment: So f-ing unintuitive. But useful answer, so thank you.

Comment: This answer is out of date since Docker for Mac