# What should I put for Docker CMD and ENTRYPOINT for Flask app running "python myapp.py images/*"

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to run a Flask app using Docker.
Normally, to execute the Flask app, I run this inside of my Terminal:

```
python myapp.py images/*
```

I am unsure of how to convert that to Docker CMD syntax (or if I need to edit ENTRYPOINT).

Here is my docker file:

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential hdf5-tools
COPY . ~/myapp/
WORKDIR ~/myapp/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["myapp.py"]
```

Inside of requirements.txt:

```
flask
numpy
h5py
tensorflow
keras
```

When I run the docker image:

```
person@person:~/Projects/$ docker run -d -p 5001:5000 myapp
19645b69b68284255940467ffe81adf0e32a8027f3a8d882b7c024a10e60de46
```

docker ps:

```
Up 24 seconds       0.0.0.0:5001->5000/tcp   hardcore_edison
```

When I got to localhost:5001 I get no response.
Is it an issue with my CMD parameter?

EDIT:
New Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential hdf5-tools
COPY . ~/myapp/
WORKDIR ~/myapp/
EXPOSE 5000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python myapp.py images/*.jpg "]
```

With this new configuration, when I run:

```
docker run -d -p 5001:5000 myapp
```

I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"python myapp.py images/*.jpg \": stat python myapp.py images/*.jpg : no such file or directory": unknown.
```

When I run:

```
docker run -d -p 5001:5000 myapp python myapp.py images/*.jpg
```

I get the Docker image to run, but now when I go to localhost:5001, it complains that the connection was reset.

Comment: First try: `docker run -d -p 5001:5000 myapp python myapp.py images/*` if that works, then change your `CMD` to `["myapp.py", "images/*"]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad you've already solved this issue. I put up this answer just for those who still have the same confusions like you do about `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` executives.
In a Dockerfile, `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are two similar executives, but still have strong difference between them. The most important one(only seems to me) is that `CMD` could be overwritten but `ENTRYPOINT` not.
To explain this, I may offer you guys the command blow:
`docker run -tid --name=container_name image_name [command]`
As we can see, `command` is optional, and it(if exists) could overwrite `CMD` defined in Dockerfile.
Let's back to your issue. You may have two ways to achieve your purpose-->

1. `ENTRYPOINT ["python"]` and `CMD ["/path/to/myapp.py", "/path/to/images/*.jpg"]`.
2. `CMD python /path/to/myapp.py /path/to/images/*.jpg`. This is mentioned by @David Maze above.

To understand the first one, you may take `CMD` as arguments for `ENTRYPOINT`.

A simple example below.

Dockerfile-->
`FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ENTRYPOINT ["cat"]
 CMD ["/etc/hosts"]`

Build image named test-cmd-show and start a container from it.
`docker run test-cmd-show`
This would show the content in `/etc/hosts` file. And go on...
`docker run test-cmd-show /etc/resolv.conf`
And this would show us the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`  file. And go on ...
`docker run test-cmd-show --help` 
This would show the help information for command `cat`.

Fantastic, right?
Somehow, we could do more research though this functionality.

Add a relevant question: [What's the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that you need a shell to expand your command line, so I’d write

```
CMD python myapp.py images/*
```

When you just write CMD like this (without the not-really-JSON brackets and quotes) Docker will implicitly feed the command line through a shell for you.

(You also might consider changing your application to support taking a directory name as configuration in some form and “baking it in” to your application, if these images will be in a fixed place in the container filesystem.)

I would only set ENTRYPOINT when (a) you are setting it to a wrapper shell script that does some first-time setup and then `exec "$@"`; or (b) when you have a `FROM scratch` image with a static binary and you literally cannot do anything with the container besides run the one binary in it.

Comment: When I change CMD to that, I get:
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"python myapp.py images/*.jpg \": stat python myapp.py images/*.jpg : no such file or directory": unknown.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I found was that the app wasn't accessible to Docker. I added this to app.run:

```
host='0.0.0.0'
```

According to this:
[Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)

Next, Docker panics when you add a directory to the CMD parameters.
So, I removed ENTRYPOINT and CMD and manually added the command to the Docker run:

```
docker docker run -d -p 5001:5000 myappdocker python myapp.py images/*.jpg
```