# The flask host adress in docker run

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask

I want to run a flask application in Docker, with the flask simple http server. (Not gunicorn)

I got a host setting problem.

In the flask app.py, it should be work as the official tutorial, but it doesn't work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

So I did it after an answer of a similar post, it suddenly works!:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43015007/3279996

```
$> flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

My question is why this first method doesn't work, but second works?

Answer (score 1):

In the first solution, when you run the code with the **python3 app.py** command, it runs on 0.0.0.0 on the host.
But the **flask run** command executes the flask app directly from the code and does not include the condition **if **name** == '**main**'**:.
On the other hand, when you run the code with **python3 app.py**, ****name**** equals **'**main**'**. But when you run the code with **flask run**, ****name**** is equal to the **FLASK_APP** variable that becomes an app in your code, and the **FLASK_APP** variable must be the same as the file name that flask app contains.

> app.py

```
print("__name__ is :", __name__)
```

> python3 app.py

```
__name__ is : __main__
```

> app.py

```
$> export FLASK_APP=app.py
$> flask run

...
__name__ is : app
...
```