# Connecting to a docker localhost port from my local machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, webserver, port

I am running a flask application inside a docker container. I would like to access the containers  port 8000
`* Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

from my host machine.

I am running the docker container via

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8000 --rm $(IMAGE_NAME) /Stocks/startserver.sh
```

When I do `docker ps`
I see the following text

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
85168e4c963e        stocks              "/Stocks/startserver…"   12 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds       127.0.0.1:8080->8000/tcp   beautiful_bartik
```

When I open localhost:8080 on my local machine I see nothing.
From my understanding the port is open, any idea why I am not able to connect to it from my host machine?
Any tips on how to debug a solution for this?

Comment: Leave out the localhost ip  like `-p 8080:8000` instead of `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8000` and try it again.

Comment: The "running on 127.0.0.1" part suggests the Flask application isn't configured to listen on the 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address, which means it won't be reachable from outside the container; [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues) describes this more.

Comment: @jdickel I already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

`Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

If that's the flask server's console output, then it sounds like you're launching it incorrectly within the container.  This looks like Flask is running on `127.0.0.1` (localhost) *inside* the container.  It needs to run on the container's external interface!

Acheive this by launching with:

```
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Or if using the (outdated) method, `app.run` within the app, pass it a `host` argument:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',
        # Any other launch args you have
        )
```

`0.0.0.0` is special address which means "all interfaces".

I'd also take @jdickel's advice, and omit `127.0.0.1` from the run command.

Comment: Doing this invalidated my CSS import. I tried doing a relative path and an absolute path. 
I get this following error.     "GET /Stocks/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -"          
I have imported it like this.           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/Stocks/css/style.css'>