# How to dynamically assign a port to a helm configuration?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, kubernetes-helm

So, I have a really simple Flask app that I'm deploying in a Kubernetes environment using helm. Now, I have the following defined in my `values.yaml`:

```
...
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 5000
  targetPort: 5000
# can add
# flaskPort: "5000"
ingress:
...
```

I know that I can set environment variables in my `helm install` command by typing `helm install python-service . --values values-dev.yaml --set flaskPort=5000` and in my python code just do :

```
PORT = os.environ.get("flaskPort")
app.run(port=PORT, debug=True, host=0.0.0.0)
```

I can also define in my `values-dev.yaml` and in my `templates/deployment.yaml` entries for this environment variable `flaskPort`. But what about the `port` and `targetPort` entries in my `values-dev.yaml`? Wouldn't that clash with whatever `flaskPort` I set? How do I modify my chart to make sure that whatever port I specify in my `helm install` command, my python app is started on that port. The python app is a small mock server which responds to simple GET/POST commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Each Kubernetes pod has its own IP address](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-networking) inside the cluster, so you don't need to worry about port conflicts.  Similarly, [each service has its own IP address](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service), distinct from the pod IP addresses, plus [its own DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/), so services can use the same ports as pods or other services without conflicts.

This means that none of this needs to be configurable at all:

- Your application can listen on whatever port is the default for its framework; for Flask that is generally port 5000.  (It does need to [listen on the special "all interfaces" address 0.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues).)
- The pod spec should reflect the same (fixed) port number.  It can help to give it a name.

  ```yaml
  ports:
    - name: http
      containerPort: 5000
  ```
- The service can use any port it likes; for an HTTP-based service I'd recommend the default HTTP port 80.  The `targetPort:` can be a name, which would match the `name:` of the corresponding pod/container port.

  ```yaml
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
  ```
- Calls to the service from within the cluster can use plain `http://svcname.nsname/` URLs, without really caring how the service is implemented, what the pod IPs are, are what ports the pods happen to be using.

At a Helm level it can make sense to make details of the service configurable; in particular if it's a NodePort or LoadBalancer service (or neither) and any of the various [cloud-provider-specific annotations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#ssl-support-on-aws).  You don't need to configure the pod's port details, particularly if you've written both the application and the Helm chart.  For example, if you run `helm create`, the [template service](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/f228a7c36c2b1c33f43a6660e01038cd8e010996/pkg/chartutil/create.go#L318) that you get doesn't allow configuring the pod's port; it's fixed in the [deployment spec](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/f228a7c36c2b1c33f43a6660e01038cd8e010996/pkg/chartutil/create.go#L291) and available to the service under the `http` name.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. So, my application can run on port 5000 within a container - I needn't configure that. Calls to the service within the cluster can use `http://svcname.nsname:80/` since `80` is defined as the port from which this service is accessible. If I change this to, say, `5000`, calls to this service from within the cluster would be to `http://svcname.nsname:5000/`, right?

Comment: Also, what does `targetPort: http` mean? I can understand `targetPort:8080` as the port on which your application within your container listens to. Does it refer to the `ports.containerPort` from the pod spec?

Also, it's probably frowned upon because it modifies the yamls created by `helm create` but, I could modify the pod spec as `containerPort: {{ .Values.flaskPort | quote }}` right?

Comment: Instead of the service's `targetPort` matching the pod's `containerPort` number, it can match the port `name`.  If you really wanted to, you could make the `containerPort` configurable like that (but it's a number, so don't `quote` it into a string).