# my simple flask application is not running sometimes it is showing the this app is not working now

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

I am running a simple flask application and I have included the Postgres and pgadmin service also in compose file for further usage.
When I am running the flask app in the browser it is showing the This app is not working

docker-compose.yml file

```
    version: '3.4'

services:
    postgresql_database:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=productdb
        ports: 
            - "5432:5432"
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment: 
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin1234
        ports:
            - '5050:80'
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    web:
        restart: always
        depends_on:
             - postgresql_database
             - pgadmin
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
volumes:
    database-data:
    pgadmin:
```

webapp.py

```
    from flask import Flask,request
from psycopg2 import Error
import psycopg2
import configparser
import csv
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods =["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return "Clv is calculated"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM python:latest
ENV LISTEN_PORT=5000
EXPOSE 5000
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","webapp.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
    flask
psycopg2
configparser
```

I am new to docker and flask can you help anyone to resolve this one

Comment: Check for the logs to see if there's any error. Also try `CMD ["flask","run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`

Comment: @Rm4n i am not getting the any error logs

Comment: Does this address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876215/13875968