# docker python flask gets " Do you want to continue" then "executor failed"

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, flask

Trying a simple [python flask web app](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/python-flask-docker/) in docker 20.10.2, build 2291f61.

Doing the: `docker build -t hello-world .` starts out ok (please see below), but ends with:

```
#6 2.866 After this operation, 305 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#6 2.866 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install python3-pip]: exit code: 1
```

Do I need to answer the question with a yes somehow? Is there some other workarond?

Edit 1: $ docker build -t flask-tutorial:latest . # does the same thing.

Edit 2: Using the install -y idea from @tentative gets a *lot* further.

```
 > [4/6] RUN apt-get install -y flask:
#7 0.742 Reading package lists...
#7 2.103 Building dependency tree...
#7 2.389 Reading state information...
#7 2.665 E: Unable to locate package flask
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y flask]: ex
it code: 100
```

Edit 3: the code [here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/develop-flask-web-apps-docker-containers-macos.html) builds an image.

Edit 4: Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu 

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
# add -y to skip the y/n prompt and install
#RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip flask
RUN apt-get install -y flask

ADD app.py /
WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [“python3”,”app.py”]
```

Edit 5: The new docker file build works. but:

```
$ docker run -i -t --name frog hello-world
/bin/sh: 1: [“python3”,”app.py”]: not found
```

Edit 6: changed the open and closed quotes above to neutral quotes. app runs fine when run from host. container get a: 27.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Edit 7: trying:

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --name frog hello-world .
```

This gets a connection refused (firefox), an empty response (chrome, edge,  and opera). This is on windows 10 with the defender turned off.

Edit 8: doing a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

then a

curl 127.0.0.1:5000 -v

gets an empty reply from server.

Edit 9: using just: app.run("0.0.0.0" works!

original output.

```
   ray@rays8350 /cygdrive/d/ray/docker/flask/myapp
    $ docker build -t hello-world .
    [+] Building 4.9s (7/9)
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                        0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
     => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest           1.6s
     => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:703218c0465075f4425e58fac0  0.0s
     => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:703218c0465075f4425e58fac0  0.0s
     => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
     => => transferring context: 28B                                           0.0s
     => CACHED [2/6] RUN apt-get update                                        0.0s
     => ERROR [3/6] RUN apt-get install python3-pip                            3.2s
    ------
     > [3/6] RUN apt-get install python3-pip:
    #6 0.588 Reading package lists...
    #6 1.927 Building dependency tree...
    #6 2.258 Reading state information...
    #6 2.683 The following additional packages will be installed:
    #6 2.683   binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential
    #6 2.683   ca-certificates cpp cpp-9 dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot file g++ g++-9 g
    c gcc-9
    #6 2.683   gcc-9-base gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
    #6 2.683   gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv libalgorithm-diff-perl
    #6 2.683   libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5 libasn1-8
    heimdal
    #6 2.683   libassuan0 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcc
    -0
    #6 2.684   libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libexpat1-
    ev
    #6 2.684   libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-9-dev libgdbm-compat4 libg
    bm6
    #6 2.684   libgomp1 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
    #6 2.684   libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libisl22 libitm1 libkrb5-26-
    eimdal
    #6 2.684   libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblocale-gettext-perl liblsan
    #6 2.684   libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpc3 libmpdec2 libmpfr6 libnpth0 libperl5.
    0
    #6 2.684   libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev
    #6 2.684   libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libquadmath0 libreadline8
    #6 2.685   libroken18-heimdal libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db
    #6 2.685   libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 libwind0-h
    imdal
    #6 2.686   linux-libc-dev make manpages manpages-dev mime-support netbase opens
    l patch
    #6 2.686   perl perl-modules-5.30 pinentry-curses python-pip-whl python3 python
    -dev
    #6 2.686   python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-pkg-resour
    es
    #6 2.686   python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-m
    nimal
    #6 2.687   readline-common xz-utils zlib1g-dev
    #6 2.690 Suggested packages:
    #6 2.690   binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-9-locales dbus-user-session libpam-systemd
    #6 2.690   pinentry-gnome3 tor debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-9-multilib gcc-9
    doc
    #6 2.690   gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-9-
    ultilib
    #6 2.690   parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon glibc-doc locales git bzr gdbm-l10n
    #6 2.690   libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
    #6 2.690   libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-sql
    #6 2.690   libstdc++-9-doc make-doc man-browser ed diffutils-doc perl-doc
    #6 2.690   libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl libb-debug-pe
    l
    #6 2.690   liblocale-codes-perl pinentry-doc python3-doc python3-tk python3-ven
    #6 2.690   python-setuptools-doc python3.8-venv python3.8-doc binfmt-support
    #6 2.690   readline-doc
    #6 3.070 The following NEW packages will be installed:
    #6 3.070   binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential
    #6 3.070   ca-certificates cpp cpp-9 dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot file g++ g++-9 g
    c gcc-9
    #6 3.070   gcc-9-base gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
    #6 3.071   gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libalgorithm-diff-perl
    #6 3.071   libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan5 libasn1-8
    heimdal
    #6 3.072   libassuan0 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcc1-0
    #6 3.072   libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libexpat1-
    ev
    #6 3.073   libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-9-dev libgdbm-compat4 libg
    bm6
    #6 3.073   libgomp1 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
    #6 3.073   libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libisl22 libitm1 libkrb5-26-
    eimdal
    #6 3.073   libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblocale-gettext-perl liblsan
    #6 3.074   libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmpc3 libmpdec2 libmpfr6 libnpth0 libperl5.
    0
    #6 3.075   libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8 libpython3.8-dev
    #6 3.075   libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libquadmath0 libreadline8
    #6 3.077   libroken18-heimdal libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db
    #6 3.077   libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++-9-dev libtsan0 libubsan1 libwind0-h
    imdal
    #6 3.077   linux-libc-dev make manpages manpages-dev mime-support netbase opens
    l patch
    #6 3.078   perl perl-modules-5.30 pinentry-curses python-pip-whl python3 python
    -dev
    #6 3.078   python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-pip
    #6 3.079   python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools python3-wheel python3.8
    #6 3.080   python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal readline-common xz-utils zlib1g-dev
    #6 3.083 The following packages will be upgraded:
    #6 3.086   gpgv libc6
    #6 3.106 2 upgraded, 113 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
    #6 3.106 Need to get 72.4 MB of archives.
    #6 3.106 After this operation, 305 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    #6 3.106 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
    ------
    executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install python3-pip]: exit code: 1
    
    ray@rays8350 /cygdrive/d/ray/docker/flask/myapp
    $
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change the `RUN` lines in the Dockerfile with `apt-get` in them to use the `-y` flag to skip asking you to confirm "yes".

The Dockerfile in the tutorial actually seems out of date or has errors in it. You need to use `pip3` now to install `Flask` and also include the `-y` flag in your `apt-get` commands. I edited the Dockerfile from the tutorial and posted below:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip && \
    pip3 install Flask

COPY app.py /

WORKDIR /

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3","app.py"]
```

**EDIT** To fix the connection issues on Windows from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329547/4676641), you can fix this by changing the main function in the Python app from:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

to this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

The reason is that you need Flask to bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of the localhost interface in the container, otherwise, it won't forward outside the container. After fixing that, you should be able to access the app at `localhost:5000` on your host machine.

Comment: it gets a lot further. see Edit 2.

Comment: @RayTayek Good! Could you actually post your entire Dockerfile for context? Thanks!

Comment: @RayTayek Could you please post the text of your actual Dockerfile in your post instead of a link? That way all context is contained in this post and won't go away if the website is moved.

Comment: please see edit 4. i also added a requirements.txt with a flask==1.0.2 in it like the one that worked, but no joy.

Comment: @RayTayek Please see updated Dockerfile. I was able to build it successfully, with the minimal `app.py` from the tutorial. You need to run `pip3 install Flask` or run `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` if you want to use a requirements file.

Comment: thanks, i will try it out. build succeds! (without the requirements file) but fails to run. please see edit 5.

Comment: @RayTayek I had this issue too and fixed by replacing the last line of your Dockerfile with the `CMD` I posted in the answer: yours had different double quote characters: `“` vs `"`

Comment: @RayTayek You should bind to the port where flask is running in the container (port `5000`) when you run it: `docker run -it -p 5000:5000 --name frog hello-world`.

Comment: making progress but still not quite right. see edit 7.

Comment: @RayTayek See edit to answer about changing to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` in the Python code. After fixing that, it should be accessible. Can confirm it works on my Windows machine.

Comment: edit 8: i put the host= in, but curl says empty response. if you have something that works maybe put up on github or rtayek at ca dot rr dot com.

Comment: @RayTayek Hm, did you already rebuild the Docker image after making the `host=0.0.0.0` changes? You need to rebuild your image for that change to take effect.

Comment: i did, but then i made another change that broke it. app.run does not like host= by itself. now it works like a charm! thank you