# Flask API and mongoDB running with docker-compose on Ubuntu VM, but when I am runing them on windows with docker desktop, getting not responding

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have recently started learning API. I did all my projects on Ubuntu VM. I used flask for API and mongoDB to store my users input, all this in Docker. When I moved my code from VM to Windows, and installed Docker desktop I have been facing this issue of "not responding" /
"The server at 172.20.0.3 is taking too long to respond."

vs code terminal output:

[image]

This is my file structure:

[image]

docker-compose.yml code:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  web:
    build: './web'
    ports: 
     - '5000:5000'
   links: 
     - db
  db:
    build: './db'
```

web/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
COPY . .
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

db/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:3.6.4
```

To check the code for app.py please use my [GitHub link](https://github.com/palharishchandra/text-similarity-flask-API).
This issue is not just for this app, it is same for my other projects which I developed in Ubuntu Virtual machine.

Comment: How are you trying to reach your web server? Do you try to access 172.20.0.3 or localhost:9000?

Comment: @ChristianFosli  http://172.20.0.3:5000/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)

Comment: 1) Unclear what you're expecting `2000:9000` to do when the default Flask port is 5000. 2) You're forwarding a host port into the container, and the container itself doesn't know that, so you cannot use the address that it prints; use `http://localhost:[port]`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have updated the code, the code in docker-compose.yml to 5000:5000, please don't get confuse

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have already checked that link, my app.py have that implementation, you can check the Git-hub link in desc to check the code. Issue is not that I am doing it first time, i have used same docker in Ubuntu it works there.

Comment: Please keep your code in sync with the question here. Also refer [mcve]. Regardless, you should still be connecting to `http://localhost:5000`, and you should be using Docker Desktop if you're on Windows