# jgroup_bind_addr in Docker container

Tags: docker, infinispan, jgroups

I am moving one application from server to docker in Azure infra. How to map jgroup_bind_addr for ever changing pod ip?

```
 <TCP bind_port="${jgroups.bind_port}"
     bind_addr="${jgroups.bind_addr}"
 >
```

Comment: Usually applications that run in Docker containers need to bind to 0.0.0.0, "everywhere", and you use Docker-level controls to map those to only specific host interfaces if required.  [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues) is probably the most prominent specific instance of this I can think of, but the answer is generic across anything running in Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Infinispan images bind to `SITE_LOCAL` which mean "Picks a site local IP address, e.g. from the 192.168.0.0 or 10.0.0.0 address range"

In the [JGroups Configuration](http://jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#Transport) you can check other possible values available for `bind_addr`. Look for `The following special values are also recognized for bind_addr` after the table.