# Python Pyctuator with Flask : Failed registering with boot-admin, [ Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address (<class 'OSError'>) -

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, spring-boot-actuator, uvicorn

I have a python application that needs monitoring. So, I decided to deploy application using flask and monitor health with pyctuator. My app.py is

```
from pyctuator.pyctuator import Pyctuator

app_name = "Flask App with Pyctuator"
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
   """Function to test the functionality of the API"""
   return "Hello, world!"
Pyctuator(
   app,
   app_name,
   app_url="http://host.docker.internal:5000",
   pyctuator_endpoint_url="http://host.docker.internal:5000/pyctuator",
   registration_url="http://localhost:8080/instances"
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

I have mentioned to expose 8080 port in docker file

```
EXPOSE 8080
```

But when I deploy my application to gcp, I get this error

```
WARNING:root:Failed registering with boot-admin, [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address (<class 'OSError'>)
```

PS: When i try to deply using uvicorn (without pyctuator), i don't see any issue of running in localhost.

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "service.app:app", "--port", "8080"]
```

Comment: Do you need `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`, as in [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)?

Comment: It is giving the same error even with ```app.run(host='0.0.0.0')``` .

Answer (score 0):

According to https://pypi.org/project/pyctuator/

you should run your app with your flask port (5000) rather than with your spring boot port (8080) so the correct version should be

```
from pyctuator.pyctuator import Pyctuator

app_name = "Flask App with Pyctuator"
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
   """Function to test the functionality of the API"""
   return "Hello, world!"
Pyctuator(
   app,
   app_name,
   app_url="http://host.docker.internal:5000",
   pyctuator_endpoint_url="http://host.docker.internal:5000/pyctuator",
   registration_url="http://localhost:8080/instances"
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: It is the same even with 5000 port