# Docker compose: Cannot access Flask from localhost

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, redis

I am trying to access Flask app from the [Docker compose getting started tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) from my local host but without making changes to this pruned Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This if my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: flask run
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /code 
    environment:
      - ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
        ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - target: 5000
        published: 8000      
    networks:
      - counter-net
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    networks:
      - counter-net
      
networks:
  counter-net:
  
volumes:
  volume-net:
```

When I use docker compose up I can see: *Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000* but I cannot access it on Running on 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000

I can see 2_counter-net when I list networks and if relevant earlier I tried creating a volume but removed this when I changed the source to . and it came up without error.

How can I correct my config please?

Comment: If it says `running on http://127.0.0.1:...` it will be inaccessible from outside its own container; also see [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues).  Your Compose [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) has incorrect syntax and this is potentially contributing to the problem.

Comment: (You should be able to successfully remove all of the `networks:`, `volumes:`, and `command:` settings without affecting your application.  Do make sure you've included a correct `CMD` in your Dockerfile.)

Comment: Thanks for the information, an environment catch, though leaving the Dockerfile unedited is a requirement here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) so that ports opened in the container can be forwarded to ports on your host computer. It's true that you could remove the user-defined network and just rely on the default bridge network (by removing all the "networks" sections from the YAML file). That should solve your problem. However, [Docker doesn't recommend this approach for production](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network).

The other option is to add a [bridge driver](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver-1) to your user-defined network specification:

```yaml
networks:
  counter-net:
    driver: bridge
```

And David is right, you should fix the YAML in your environment.

```yaml
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=app.py
      - FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: The [`default` network that Compose provides](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) is a "user-defined bridge network" in the language of the base Docker layer.  There's nothing wrong with using it.  `driver: bridge` is probably the default for a Compose network and you shouldn't need to specify it (it's not harmful but not helpful either).

Comment: I've run a small test and David is correct. You do not need to specify the driver in user-created docker compose networks in order to access containers from the host. Unfortunately, I cannot delete my answer because it has been accepted.