# Flask app is running in localhost but not running in Docker Containe

Tags: python-3.x, docker, localhost, docker-container

I have made a basic temperature converter web app using python Flask and when i am running in using the command
`python3 main.py
Then it is runnning fine.
But after building dockerfile and running in container it is not running
dockerfile is build completely with no error and also the port mapping is correctly done

My flask app is running properly in the local host but when i try running in docker container it is not able to run in the mapped port

Here is the python code in main.py file

```
from flask import Flask

from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")

def index():

    celsius = request.args.get("celsius", "")

    if celsius:

        fahrenheit = fahrenheit_from(celsius)

    else:

        fahrenheit = ""

    return (

        """<form action="" method="get">

                Celsius temperature: <input type="text" name="celsius">

                <input type="submit" value="Convert to Fahrenheit">

            </form>"""

        + "Fahrenheit: "

        + fahrenheit

    )


def fahrenheit_from(celsius):

    """Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit degrees."""

    try:

        fahrenheit = float(celsius) * 9 / 5 + 32

        fahrenheit = round(fahrenheit, 3)  # Round to three decimal places

        return str(fahrenheit)

    except ValueError:

        return "invalid input"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=3000, debug=True)
`
```

Here is the DockerFile code

[image]

Comment: It's unclear from your question but the `Dockerfile` `EXPOSE` command is for documentation only. It does not change ports exposed by the container. If you're using the default Flask port (`5000`) and you're confident Flask is binding to `0.0.0.0`, then you will want to `docker run .... --publish=5000:5000/tcp ....` to ensure Docker exposes the container's port `5000` on your host's port `5000`. If you're running on Window or a Mac this may not be true but, on Linux, you can then access the app on the host as `localhost:5000`

Comment: Please don't use images in questions when it's straightforward to copy-and-paste the text. Images may not live as long as the question and they inhibit others' ability to copy-and-paste text to help answer your questions.

Comment: Do you see the port open with command 'ss -ntl'?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.
So by changing this line in your Python code it will work.
See "Externally Visible Server" in the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=3000, debug=True)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329547/4413446) for detail.

## Note on `EXPOSE`

You need to expose the port when you run the container, using `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile does not do that.

> The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. [source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

You need to publish / expose it when you run the container. See reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose).

```bash
docker run -p 3000:3000 ...
```

Comment: yes i am exposing the port in while running the container but still it doesn't run in the container

Comment: @Goku Could you share the way you run and test the container because without this information it's hard to help you.

Comment: i run the container using the following command: docker run -dp 3000:3000 myapp

Comment: @Goku I think I found your issue, please have a look and tell me.

Comment: please tell me where I am going wrong. I don't understand the issue.

Comment: @Goku It's due to the IP you are using in your Python code. Have you read my answer?