# Flask app not running in docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am learning docker using flask application.Here is the below code I am using

app.py

```
from flask import Flask



app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  flask:
    build: .
    image: myapp:latest
```

When I tried to run the above flask app through **python3 app.py** it works on the port 5000 correctly.But when I tried to dockerize it **docker compose up --build** shows that the app is started no error or warning logs but localhost is not getting connected

[![localhost not connected][1]][1]

In Dockerfile I tried specifying the host also.Nothing worked. Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue?

I have tried all the solutions mentioned in this link [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues)

But still having the same issue. I have created a virtual env for this flask app and trying to run the docker container. After changing

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

and tried docker run <container_id> got the following console response

[image: Terminal response]
Kindly look all the attached image for clear reference

I could see that the app is running in my localhost as well as in some other ip.Attaching the below screenshot for the reference. Can some one address this issue?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yboh.png

Answer (score 1):

Change docker-compose to this

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  flask:
    build: .
    image: myapp:latest
    ports:
     - "5000"
```

Comment: I tried with the above changes.Still the same issue. Localhost is unknown

Comment: try `ports: - "5000:5000"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to map a port in docker. To do that, add a ports field to your `docker-compose.yml` file. For example:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  flask:
    build: .
    image: myapp:latest
    ports:
      - "81:80"
```

The Flask server will listen on port 80. You can now access the application using port 81 on your machine. [More detail](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)