# Application is running in Docker but Localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile

I am new to docker and would really appretiate any help on this. I am running an python flask application in a docker container.

I am using the below command to run the docker image:
`docker container run -d -p 5000:8051 rep1/doc-image:0.0.1.RELEASE`

Below is my docker Logs which show my flask app running

```
2023-07-18 20:07:18 Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8051/
2023-07-18 20:07:18 
2023-07-18 20:07:18  * Serving Flask app 'main'
2023-07-18 20:07:18  * Debug mode: off
2023-07-18 20:07:18 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
2023-07-18 20:07:18  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8051
2023-07-18 20:07:18 Press CTRL+C to quit
```

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8051
CMD [ "python","./main.py" ]
```

I can see that port 5000 is being properly mapped to port 8051 from the output of `docker ps` command
`0.0.0.0:5000->8051/tcp`

But still on running `localhost:5000`, I am getting the error:
*This page isn’t working Localhost didn’t send any data*

I tried specifing the host address when running the command for running docker image, incase the host address in docker is different than localhost, but I am again getting the same error.
`docker container run -d -h localhost -p 5000:8051 rep1/doc-image:0.0.1.RELEASE`

Comment: The `Running on http://127.0.0.1:...` message suggests a misconfiguration that means the server won't be reachable from outside its own container.  If you're using Flask, does [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues) help you?