# I can't open http://127.0.0.1:5000 when I run my Flask project with Docker

Tags: docker, flask, wordle-game

I implemented a wordle game based on Flask and MySQL: https://github.com/Goer17/wordle-flask

When I run my program with Docker, the console shows that:

```
web-1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app.py'
web-1  |  * Debug mode: off
web-1  | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
web-1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

But I find it that I can't open the link as my browser trigger a 403 error.

The following are my docker-compose.yaml and Dockerfile:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: app.py
      FLASK_ENV: development
  db:
    image: mysql:innovation-oracle
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordle
      # MYSQL_USER: user
      # MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN flask db init

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

You can see more information in my repo.

I attempted to run my program directly without using Docker, and it successfully executed.

Comment: You are publishing the service on host port `5001`, so you would need to use `http://localhost:5001`. If you want it available o port 5000, then don't publish it on port 5001.

Comment: I have tried it before, but it seems that I still can't open http://localhost:5001.(ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Comment: The output `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000` suggests you haven't configured Flask's dev server to accept connections from outside Docker.  Does [Deploying a minimal flask app in docker - server connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323224/deploying-a-minimal-flask-app-in-docker-server-connection-issues) help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project looks something like this:

```
├── app.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
└── requirements.txt
```

The `requirements.txt` must specify `Flask`.

`Dockerfile` (I have commented out `flask db init` because I don't know what you have implemented there.)

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

# RUN flask db init

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: app.py
      FLASK_ENV: development
  db:
    image: mysql:innovation-oracle
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordle
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```

`app.y` (A test application.)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

In your Docker Compose configuration you are mapping port 5000 on the container to port 5001 on the host. So to connect to the app you need to browse to http://127.0.0.1:5001.

[image]